# Firebase Promises in array not resolving in time

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I am trying to return 3 promises from my firebase DB and once all three promises have been fulfilled I basically want to render a new page or do whatever. So I do a Promise.All(...) but my lists are still empty afterwards.

My queries are correct because when I console.log() within each of those functions, I get the objects returned from my DB but my Promise.All isn't waiting for those promises to resolve and instead executes the code within the Promise.All which is returning empty lists.

```js
app.get('...', function (req, res) {
  //Return first promise from DB save to zone_obj list
  var zone_key = req.params.id;
  var zone_obj = [];
  firebase.database().ref(...).once('value').then((snapme) => {
    zone_obj.push(snapme.val());
  });
  
  //Return second promise from DB save to members list
  var members = [];
  firebase.database().ref(...).on("value", function (snapshott) {
    snapshott.forEach((snapper) => {
      members.push(snapper.val());
    });
  });
  
  //Return third promise from DB save to experiences list
  var experiences = [];
  firebase.database().ref(...).on("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
      firebase.database().ref(...).once("value").then((snapit) => {
        experiences.push(snapit);
      });
    });
   });
   
  //once all promises have resolved
  Promise.all([experiences,zone_obj,members]).then(values => {
    console.log(values[0]); //returns []
    console.log(values[1]); //returns []
    console.log(values[2]); //returns []
  });
});
```

Comment: callback to `on('value',` ... is asynchronous - you're executing promise.all before any `on('value'` could possibly be "fired"

Comment: also, your array in Promise.all is an array of (empty due to above issue) arrays, could never be an array of promises

Answer (score 2):

This is not actually firebase's problem. Firebase method `.on("value")` is actually a listener that will be bound to firebase to get real-time updates and that is not actually a promise and your callback function will be called every time when data on that node is changed. so if you want to save or get data only once use `firebase.database().ref(...).set()` and `firebase.database().ref(...).once()` method respectively.

According to firebase docs

On method

```
on(eventType, callback, cancelCallbackOrContext, context) returns function()
```

once method

```
once(eventType, successCallback, failureCallbackOrContext, context) returns firebase.Promise containing any type
```

So change your code to following

```
app.get('...', function (req, res) {
    var promises = []

    //Return first promise from DB save to zone_obj list
    promises.push(firebase.database().ref(...).once('value'));

    //Return second promise from DB save to members list
    promises.push(firebase.database().ref(...).once('value'));

    //Return third promise from DB save to experiences list
    promises.push(firebase.database().ref(...).once('value'));

    //once all promises have resolved
    Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
        console.log(values[0]); // zone_obj 
        console.log(values[1]); // members 
        console.log(values[2]); // experiences 
    });
});
```