# Firebase cloud functions promise.all

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

After going through simple examples on cloud functions that worked, I want to test something more complex. I have created a table (BTDevices) table in the Firebase realtime database, populated with few data:

[image]

Now I want my cloud function to use the MAC addresses for retrieving the "userId" fields. This is a snippet of my JavaScript cloud function:

```js
var getUserIdPromisesArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < nearbyMACsArray.length; i++) {
  var tmpNearbyMAC = nearbyMACsArray[i];
  var promise = admin.database().ref(`${DB_BT_DEVICES}/${tmpNearbyMAC}/userId`).once('value');
  getUserIdPromisesArray.push(promise);
}

return Promise.all(getUserIdPromisesArray).then(results => {
  results.forEach(result => {
    var userId = result.val();
    console.log('result.val() = ', result.val());
  });
});
```

From other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879695/promise-all-with-firebase-datasnapshot-foreach), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683065/firebase-promises-in-array-not-resolving-in-time), and [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html), I know that I need to first create all my promises, and when they are done, then process the fetched data. So the for-loop iterates the nearbyMACsArray that contains the MAC addresses, creates a promise, and pushes it to the getUserIdPromisesArray.

Then I wait for all promises to finish and iterate the "results" array to print the read value, but the cloud function log shows a null value in one of the outputs:

[image: output log]

Any ideas on why this is happening? Am I missing something with the promises?
Thanks.

Comment: can you export this table and provide us it´s JSON?

Comment: Thanks, eventually the issue was with the populated data at first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [val()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val) returns null when there is no data at the requested location.  This is most likely what's going on.  It's not likely a problem with your promises.

Comment: Thanks Doug for the fast reply, indeed there was an issue with the populated data, and they were not actually in the database!